# Drupal localhost redirecting to www.localhost.com

Tags: php, drupal, redirect

I am working on a drupal site which I checked out (svn) to my localhost.

Now the problem is that when I go to:

> http://www.site.com

it all works fine, but when I go to:

> http://localhost/work/site

I get redirected to

> http://www.localhost.com/work/site

I have ran the install.php script and all works great. It reinstalls everything but when I go to the main site the redirect occurs.

I removed the .htaccess file, didn't do anything.

I am using windows 7 ultimate 64 (also tried on winxp pro 32) apache 2.2, php 5.2.13

Anyone know anyway to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: do you have nod32 antivirus by any chance?

Comment: nope! Avast in the windows 7 pc and no antivirus on the windows xp machine

Comment: is apache running? have you tried a vanilla drupal install?

Comment: @Robert: Yes of course apache is running and yes I have installed other drupal on other directories and they worked

Answer (score 12):

The redirect is caused by Firefox not being able to get a good connection with the local server and then trying to "fix" the address.  You can disable the behavior in Firefox as follows:

1. Type about:config in the address bar
   and hit return.
2. Find browser.fixup.alternate.enabled.
3. Double click the “true” value. The line will become bold, and the
   value will change to “false” [from here](https://rolfje.wordpress.com/2008/05/06/no-more-wwwlocalhostcom/)

However that will not solve your underlying problem (local server isn't responding right), it will just get rid of really annoying behavior. There are several possible causes of this failure, the host file problem MatW suggested is a common cause.

In my case Drupal seems to be crashing Apache during certain page loads, which is hard to diagnose/fix when your browser keeps redirecting itself away from the page you need to refresh.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked your window's hosts file? Not sure about where it lives in Windows 7, but in XP it lives here:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Make sure there is an entry like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

As a double-check, you may want to flush your PCs DNS cache. Go into the command line and type:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Comment: I have other websites working perfectly so this is not the problem

Comment: How bizarre! If it's not this or an .htaccess / httpd.conf issue, then I have no idea what it could be...

Comment: I'm having the same isssue right now, that isn't helping.  it's been working for 6 months and today Firefox is resolving to www.localhost.com

Answer (score 0):

From the drupal sites/default/settings.php file:

```
/**
 * Base URL (optional).
 *
 * If you are experiencing issues with different site domains,
 * uncomment the Base URL statement below (remove the leading hash sign)
 * and fill in the absolute URL to your Drupal installation.
 *
 * You might also want to force users to use a given domain.
 * See the .htaccess file for more information.
 *
 * Examples:
 *   $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';
 *   $base_url = 'http://www.example.com:8888';
 *   $base_url = 'http://www.example.com/drupal';
 *   $base_url = 'https://www.example.com:8888/drupal';
 *
 * It is not allowed to have a trailing slash; Drupal will add it
 * for you.
 */
# $base_url = 'http://www.example.com';  // NO trailing slash!
```

Try setting $base_url = 'http://localhost/work/site';

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason behind this huge problem.

It was the css and js optimization that was messing everything up.
I set those two to off and then copied the database to the localhost version of the site and all worked out great!!!

Comment: set those two to off means...? how can i set that..?