# My http://localhost/ redirecting to www.localhost.com

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, xampp, htdocs

I checked my `httpd.conf` file and nothing found anything, let me know other areas whr i need to look.

Although my other links are working fine like --

`http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` or `http://localhost/myprojects/`

This is what i have in my httpd.conf file -

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Lastly-- **YES** i googled a lot before asking but unable to find any in my case.

Apache is working --

[image: Working]

My hhtpd.conf file --

```
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2> for detailed information.
# In particular, see 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directives.html>
# for a discussion of each configuration directive.
#
# Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
# what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
# consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
#
# Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
# of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
# server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
# with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so "logs/foo.log"
# with ServerRoot set to "C:/xampp/apache" will be interpreted by the
# server as "C:/xampp/apache/logs/foo.log".
#
# NOTE: Where filenames are specified, you must use forward slashes
# instead of backslashes (e.g., "c:/apache" instead of "c:\apache").
# If a drive letter is omitted, the drive on which httpd.exe is located
# will be used by default.  It is recommended that you always supply
# an explicit drive letter in absolute paths to avoid confusion.

#
# ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
# configuration, error, and log files are kept.
#
# Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
# ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to point the LockFile directive
# at a local disk.  If you wish to share the same ServerRoot for multiple
# httpd daemons, you will need to change at least LockFile and PidFile.
#
ServerRoot "C:/xampp/apache"

#
# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
# ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
# directive.
#
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
#Listen 0.0.0.0:80
#Listen [::]:80
Listen 80

#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
#
# To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
# have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
# directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
# Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
# to be loaded here.
#
# Example:
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
#
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
#LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
#LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
#LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
#LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
#LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
#LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
#LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
#LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
#LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
#LoadModule case_filter_module modules/mod_case_filter.so
#LoadModule case_filter_in_module modules/mod_case_filter_in.so
#LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
#LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
#LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
#LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule dav_lock_module modules/mod_dav_lock.so
#LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
#LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
#LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
#LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
#LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
#LoadModule example_module modules/mod_example.so
#LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
#LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
#LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
#LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
#LoadModule ident_module modules/mod_ident.so
#LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
#LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
#LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
#LoadModule log_forensic_module modules/mod_log_forensic.so
#LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
#LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
#LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
#LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
#LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
#LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
#LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
#LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
#LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
#LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
#LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
#LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
#LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
#
# If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
# httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
#
# User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
# It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
# running httpd, as with most system services.
#
User daemon
Group daemon

</IfModule>
</IfModule>

# 'Main' server configuration
#
# The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
# server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
# <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
# any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
#
# All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
# in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
# virtual host being defined.
#

#
# ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
# e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
# as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
#
ServerAdmin postmaster@localhost

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName localhost:80

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs"

#
# Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
# to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
# directory (and its subdirectories). 
#
# First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
# features.  
#
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

#
# Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
# particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
# you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
# below.
#

#
# This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>

#
# DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
# is requested.
#
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm
</IfModule>

#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
# viewed by Web clients. 
#
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>

#
# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
# container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
# logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
# container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
#
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"

#ScriptLog "logs/cgi.log"

#
# LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
#
LogLevel warn

<IfModule log_config_module>
    #
    # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
    # a CustomLog directive (see below).
    #
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common

    <IfModule logio_module>
      # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
      LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>

    #
    # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
    # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
    # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
    # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
    # logged therein and *not* in this file.
    #
    #CustomLog "logs/access.log" common

    #
    # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
    # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
    #
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule alias_module>
    #
    # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
    # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
    # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
    # Example:
    # Redirect permanent /foo http://localhost/bar

    #
    # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
    # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
    # Example:
    # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
    #
    # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
    # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
    # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
    # the filesystem path.

    #
    # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
    # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
    # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
    # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
    # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
    # directives as to Alias.
    #
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/"

</IfModule>

<IfModule cgid_module>
    #
    # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
    # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
    #
    #Scriptsock "logs/cgi.sock"
</IfModule>

#
# "C:/xampp/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
# CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
#
<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

#
# DefaultType: the default MIME type the server will use for a document
# if it cannot otherwise determine one, such as from filename extensions.
# If your server contains mostly text or HTML documents, "text/plain" is
# a good value.  If most of your content is binary, such as applications
# or images, you may want to use "application/octet-stream" instead to
# keep browsers from trying to display binary files as though they are
# text.
#
DefaultType text/plain

<IfModule mime_module>
    #
    # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
    # filename extension to MIME-type.
    #
    TypesConfig "conf/mime.types"

    #
    # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
    # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
    #
    #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
    #
    # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
    # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
    #
    #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
    #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
    #
    # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
    # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
    #
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

    #
    # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
    # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
    # or added with the Action directive (see below)
    #
    # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
    # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp

    # For type maps (negotiated resources):
    #AddHandler type-map var

    #
    # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
    #
    # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
    # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
    #
    AddType text/html .shtml
    AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_magic_module>
    #
    # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
    # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
    # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
    #
    MIMEMagicFile "conf/magic"
</IfModule>

#
# Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
# 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
#
# Some examples:
#ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
#ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
#ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
#ErrorDocument 402 http://localhost/subscription_info.html
#

#
# EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
# memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall is used to deliver
# files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
# be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
# filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
# broken on your system.
#
#EnableMMAP off
#EnableSendfile off

# Supplemental configuration
#
# The configuration files in the conf/extra/ directory can be 
# included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
# the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
# necessary.

# XAMPP specific settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-xampp.conf"

# Perl settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-perl.conf"

# Server-pool management (MPM specific)
Include "conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf"

# Multi-language error messages
Include "conf/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf"

# Fancy directory listings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf"

# Language settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-languages.conf"

# User home directories
Include "conf/extra/httpd-userdir.conf"

# Real-time info on requests and configuration
Include "conf/extra/httpd-info.conf"

# Virtual hosts
Include "conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"

# Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
# Attention! WEB_DAV is a security risk without a new userspecific configuration for a secure authentifcation 
# Include "conf/extra/httpd-dav.conf"

# Implements a proxy/gateway for Apache.
Include "conf/extra/httpd-proxy.conf"

# Various default settings
Include "conf/extra/httpd-default.conf"

# Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
Include "conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf"
#
# Note: The following must must be present to support
#       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
#       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
    SSLSessionCache "shmcb:logs/ssl.scache(512000)"
    SSLSessionCacheTimeout 300
</IfModule>

# AJP13 Proxy
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: any .htaccess in there? in the root dir

Comment: @HankyPanky No htaccess i already checked under C:\xampp\htdocs

Comment: check you proxy settings...it should say no-proxy for localhost

Comment: have you tried http://localhost/ in your browser?

Comment: @Renku yes i tried in FF

Comment: @swapnesh try it with a real browser...like opera :)

Comment: ¿Have you checked the `Virtual Hosts` at the end of httpd.conf?

Comment: any index file in that folder causing a redirect?

Comment: @FelipeAlamedaA I pasted the httpd.conf file..i checked the virtual host but unable to locate the cause :(

Comment: Do you have an application installed in the root directory of your website? Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal, Moodle, etc?

Comment: what happens with http://127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: @SalmanA yes i worked on those..so these CMS/FW are in htdocs ...can it over ride the base settings ??

Comment: @halilb It works correctly..although i need to figure the cause for the problem

Comment: (i) Which CMS/FW is in the root directory? (ii) it can redirect regardless of _base settings_. An `index.php` with `header("Location: http://www.localhost.com")` for example. Some FWs come with their own `.htaccess`.

Comment: @SalmanA Wordpress/joomla/pyrocms/zend yes header() can do this but how its affecting the http://localhost/  ??

Comment: thank you for this important question, its work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging by your comments, seems like you might be looking at the wrong place. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822683/drupal-localhost-redirecting-to-www-localhost-com?rq=1).

Perhaps the application installed in the root directory (the one you expect to see when you type `http://localhost/index.php`) is configured incorrectly. Locate the application whose index.php file is in the root, then go through its configuration files and see if you can find `www.localhost.com` written somewhere. Some applications store their settings in database so that is another place to look at.

Comment: thx for the link i will look into it and move forward with this..once done..i will surely let u know +1 for the current efforts :)

Comment: finally its working ..awesome..u read my head and words correctly :) and yes it was a issue from htaccess in one of my zend project..however there is nothing www.localhost.com but on renaming the file I successfully manage to make it working :)

Answer (score 9):

here is a nice article about this helpful feature of Firefox that becomes annoying once you have fixed the problem and still get redirected:
Filed under ‘Annoying things I keep forgetting how to fix…’:

To disable this ‘feature’ do the following:

```
Type about:config in the browser bar
Type browser.fixup.alternate.enabled in the search box that appears
Right click on the browser.fixup.alternate.enabled that appears in the filtered list below and choose Toggle to set the value to false
```

[http://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/disable-firefox-redirecting-to-localhost-com/](https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/disable-firefox-redirecting-to-localhost-com/)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, all of my browsers were redirecting `http://localhost/mysite` or `localhost/mysite` to `www.localhost.com/mysite` on manually installed php,apache and mysql system. replacing 127.0.0.1 with localhost was working perfectly means my installation of W.A.M.P perfectly running. i tried to solve it according to Salman way but no luck. i did not look into C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts file, i knew even host files do not have 127.0.0.1 localhost entry, doesn't matter at all because it is built in the system by default.

problem was solved by deactivating my avast antivirus shields, which were causing such unusual browser behavior. if you face such a problem you can try deactivating your antivirus shields first before you jump into any deep technical solution.

Answer (score 3):

Are you by any chance using chrome? Because chrome is not good about this kind of stuff sometimes, try different browsers, if that duos not help..

Then you MUST have a `.htaccess` file somewhere in your `www` directory.

try searching for it. It is an unusual file, it duos not have  name just an extension.

try searching like `%.htaccess`

if that duos not help go to `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc` and open the file `hosts` as a admin so you can edit it and look up if some program inserted something inside.

**ALSO**

Just remembered a situation i had earlier. Some .php files can have redirects in them. Check your index.php or main.php or index.phtml or some other extenson if they do a redirect, becouse it could be somone wrote a code to redirect the script.

see this example to understand it bether:
[WWW to non-WWW Redirect with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079457/www-to-non-www-redirect-with-php)

Comment: thanks for more stuff to look into :) upvoted +1 for chrome and new stuff

Comment: Avoid offensive words in your posts.

Comment: @Sangoku my host file looks good --  # localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost

Comment: Did you try to search for the  htaccess file? it is the only possible explanation now  that you ruled out the route. Just in case try dns reslove of your localhost. But i bet there is a htaccess file somwhere hiden...

Comment: @swapnesh Read the edit i just made, if there is no htaccess file then the code it self must be redirecting him self. It is a common practise to use header() function to redirect from $__SERVER['forgot the name'] to www.$__SERVER['forgot the name']

Comment: @Sangoku issue solved ..find my comments under SalmanA answer :) thx a lot for ur every help :)

Comment: Clearing cache in Chrome helped me in getting around this problem.

Answer (score 2):

I also face that issue. But my issues is now resolved. I just disable the TeamViewer. So the reason behind that issue may be another application running in same port.
Thanks @Jibran Kassim.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a quite old question but just for the same problem, which appeared suddenly. This was due to an issue in the PHP code, and nothing due to Apache configuration.

I checked the file `/var/log/apache2/error.log` (Under Linux, I do not know the path for Windows/Mac), which gave me an indication:

> [Sat Jun 20 21:49:06.444684 2015] [:error] [pid 24149] [client 127.0.0.1:59150] PHP Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context in /docs/Cedric/Programmation/PHP/slnslv/src/SLN/RegisterBundle/Controller/MemberController.php on line 80, referer: http://localhost/slnslv/web/
>
> [Sat Jun 20 21:49:06.674815 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1904] AH00052: child pid 1973 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
>
> [Sat Jun 20 21:49:06.674885 2015] [core:notice] [pid 1904] AH00052: child pid 24149 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

Fixing the error in PHP with this indication magically solved the problem.

No idea however how a simple PHP error can cause a segmentation fault, which can make the browser (Firefox) thing it should guess a correct domain name.

Comment: Good to see that u put your efforts even to an old question +1

Answer (score 1):

Solved for me by this:
first I understood other browsers in my system work fine with http://localhost
then
I cleared my main browser cache
It worked

................
Of course Samlam 's replay is the answer satisfied the questioner
But I answered this here because of question title.
Most of guys have same problem as I do and they are referred to this page.

Comment: Finally! Same problem here. It only happened on Firefox. I solved the problem by clearing the cached data for 'localhost'. You can simply clear the cache if you don't mind losing all cached data.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, remember to clear your browser cache after making changes.

Answer (score -3):

you cant see localhost by `www.localhost.com` you can see by `http://localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Bro this is not the problem actually..THRE PROBLEM WAS - If i am typing http://localhost/ in my browser it gets redirected to this URL -> www.localhost.com . Salmam provided the answer for the fix ..please have a look at it for future reference.

Comment: type: 127.0.0.1; what is your browser?

Comment: this is going to work, but my question was why its not taking(redirection) http://locahost ?

Comment: perhaps your browser have add one and redirect all of the words to http://yourword.com or your browser cant match by OS or your browser have a local "localhost"