# http://localhost/ redirecting to www.localhost.com

Tags: apache

I installed XAMP on my mac. when i try to open

> `http://localhost`

I get redirected to `"http://www.localhost.com/index.php"` I installed it on a brand new system and I tested it with several Browsers but still same problems

> ```
> #
> # This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
> # configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
> # See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/> for detailed information.
> # In particular, see 
> # <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/directives.html>
> # for a discussion of each configuration directive.
> #
> # Do NOT simply read the instructions in here without understanding
> # what they do.  They're here only as hints or reminders.  If you are unsure
> # consult the online docs. You have been warned.  
> #
> # Configuration and logfile names: If the filenames you specify for many
> # of the server's control files begin with "/" (or "drive:/" for Win32), the
> # server will use that explicit path.  If the filenames do *not* begin
> # with "/", the value of ServerRoot is prepended -- so 'log/access_log'
> # with ServerRoot set to '/www' will be interpreted by the
> # server as '/www/log/access_log', where as '/log/access_log' will be
> # interpreted as '/log/access_log'.
>
> #
> # ServerRoot: The top of the directory tree under which the server's
> # configuration, error, and log files are kept.
> #
> # Do not add a slash at the end of the directory path.  If you point
> # ServerRoot at a non-local disk, be sure to specify a local disk on the
> # Mutex directive, if file-based mutexes are used.  If you wish to share the
> # same ServerRoot for multiple httpd daemons, you will need to change at
> # least PidFile.
> #
> ServerRoot "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles"
>
> # 
> # Mutex: Allows you to set the mutex mechanism and mutex file directory
> # for individual mutexes, or change the global defaults
> # 
> # Uncomment and change the directory if mutexes are file-based and the default
> # mutex file directory is not on a local disk or is not appropriate for some
> # other reason.
> #
> # Mutex default:logs
>
> #
> # Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
> # ports, instead of the default. See also the <VirtualHost>
> # directive.
> #
> # Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
> # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
> #
> #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
> Listen 80
>
> #
> # Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
> #
> # To be able to use the functionality of a module which was built as a DSO you
> # have to place corresponding `LoadModule' lines at this location so the
> # directives contained in it are actually available _before_ they are used.
> # Statically compiled modules (those listed by `httpd -l') do not need
> # to be loaded here.
> #
> # Example:
> # LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
> #
> LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
> LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
> LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
> LoadModule authn_dbd_module modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
> LoadModule authn_socache_module modules/mod_authn_socache.so
> LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
> LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
> LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
> LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
> LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
> LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
> LoadModule authz_dbd_module modules/mod_authz_dbd.so
> LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
> LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
> LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
> LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
> LoadModule auth_form_module modules/mod_auth_form.so
> LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
> LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
> LoadModule file_cache_module modules/mod_file_cache.so
> LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
> LoadModule cache_disk_module modules/mod_cache_disk.so
> LoadModule socache_shmcb_module modules/mod_socache_shmcb.so
> LoadModule socache_dbm_module modules/mod_socache_dbm.so
> LoadModule socache_memcache_module modules/mod_socache_memcache.so
> LoadModule dbd_module modules/mod_dbd.so
> LoadModule bucketeer_module modules/mod_bucketeer.so
> LoadModule dumpio_module modules/mod_dumpio.so
> LoadModule echo_module modules/mod_echo.so
> LoadModule case_filter_module modules/mod_case_filter.so
> LoadModule case_filter_in_module modules/mod_case_filter_in.so
> LoadModule buffer_module modules/mod_buffer.so
> LoadModule ratelimit_module modules/mod_ratelimit.so
> LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
> LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
> LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
> LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
> LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
> LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
> LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
> LoadModule charset_lite_module modules/mod_charset_lite.so
> LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
> LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
> LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
> LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
> LoadModule log_debug_module modules/mod_log_debug.so
> LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
> LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
> LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
> LoadModule cern_meta_module modules/mod_cern_meta.so
> LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
> LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
> LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
> LoadModule unique_id_module modules/mod_unique_id.so
> LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
> LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
> LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
> LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
> LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
> LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
> LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
> LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so
> LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
> LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
> LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
> LoadModule proxy_express_module modules/mod_proxy_express.so
> LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
> LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
> LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
> LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
> LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
> LoadModule lbmethod_byrequests_module modules/mod_lbmethod_byrequests.so
> LoadModule lbmethod_bytraffic_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bytraffic.so
> LoadModule lbmethod_bybusyness_module modules/mod_lbmethod_bybusyness.so
> LoadModule lbmethod_heartbeat_module modules/mod_lbmethod_heartbeat.so
> LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
> LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
> LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
> LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
> LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
> LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
> LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
> LoadModule cgid_module modules/mod_cgid.so
> LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
> LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
> LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
> LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
> LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
> LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
> LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
> LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
> LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
>
> <IfDefine JUSTTOMAKEAPXSHAPPY>
> LoadModule php4_module        modules/libphp4.so
> LoadModule php5_module        modules/libphp5.so
> </IfDefine>
>
> <IfModule unixd_module>
> #
> # If you wish httpd to run as a different user or group, you must run
> # httpd as root initially and it will switch.  
> #
> # User/Group: The name (or #number) of the user/group to run httpd as.
> # It is usually good practice to create a dedicated user and group for
> # running httpd, as with most system services.
> #
> User daemon
> Group daemon
> </IfModule>
>
> # 'Main' server configuration
> #
> # The directives in this section set up the values used by the 'main'
> # server, which responds to any requests that aren't handled by a
> # <VirtualHost> definition.  These values also provide defaults for
> # any <VirtualHost> containers you may define later in the file.
> #
> # All of these directives may appear inside <VirtualHost> containers,
> # in which case these default settings will be overridden for the
> # virtual host being defined.
> #
>
> #
> # ServerAdmin: Your address, where problems with the server should be
> # e-mailed.  This address appears on some server-generated pages, such
> # as error documents.  e.g. admin@your-domain.com
> #
> ServerAdmin you@example.com
>
> #
> # ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
> # This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
> # it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
> #
> # If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
> #
> #ServerName www.example.com:@@Port@@
> # XAMPP
> ServerName localhost
>
> #
> # Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
> # explicitly permit access to web content directories in other
> # <Directory> blocks below.
> #
> <Directory />
>     AllowOverride none
>     Require all denied
> </Directory>
>
> #
> # Note that from this point forward you must specifically allow
> # particular features to be enabled - so if something's not working as
> # you might expect, make sure that you have specifically enabled it
> # below.
> #
>
> # 
> # DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
> # documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
> # symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
> #
> DocumentRoot "/Users/danielmauch/Sites"
> <Directory "/Users/danielmauch/Sites">
>     #
>     # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
>     # or any combination of:
>     #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
>     #
>     # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
>     # doesn't give it to you.
>     #
>     # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
>     # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#options
>     # for more information.
>     #
>     #Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
>     # XAMPP
>     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
>
>     #
>     # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
>     # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
>     #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
>     #
>     #AllowOverride None
>     # since XAMPP 1.4:
>     AllowOverride All
>
>     #
>     # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
>     #
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
>
> #
> # DirectoryIndex: sets the file that Apache will serve if a directory
> # is requested.
> #
> <IfModule dir_module>
>     #DirectoryIndex index.html
>     # XAMPP
>     DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var index.php index.php3 index.php4
> </IfModule>
>
> #
> # The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being 
> # viewed by Web clients. 
> #
> <Files ".ht*">
>   Require all denied
> </Files>
>
> #
> # ErrorLog: The location of the error log file.
> # If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a <VirtualHost>
> # container, error messages relating to that virtual host will be
> # logged here.  If you *do* define an error logfile for a <VirtualHost>
> # container, that host's errors will be logged there and not here.
> #
> ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
>
> #
> # LogLevel: Control the number of messages logged to the error_log.
> # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
> # alert, emerg.
> #
> LogLevel warn
>
> <IfModule log_config_module>
>     #
>     # The following directives define some format nicknames for use with
>     # a CustomLog directive (see below).
>     #
>     LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
>     LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
>
>     <IfModule logio_module>
>       # You need to enable mod_logio.c to use %I and %O
>       LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
>     </IfModule>
>
>     #
>     # The location and format of the access logfile (Common Logfile Format).
>     # If you do not define any access logfiles within a <VirtualHost>
>     # container, they will be logged here.  Contrariwise, if you *do*
>     # define per-<VirtualHost> access logfiles, transactions will be
>     # logged therein and *not* in this file.
>     #
>     CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
>
>     #
>     # If you prefer a logfile with access, agent, and referer information
>     # (Combined Logfile Format) you can use the following directive.
>     #
>     #CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
> </IfModule>
>
> <IfModule alias_module>
>     #
>     # Redirect: Allows you to tell clients about documents that used to 
>     # exist in your server's namespace, but do not anymore. The client 
>     # will make a new request for the document at its new location.
>     # Example:
>     # Redirect permanent /foo http://www.example.com/bar
>
>     #
>     # Alias: Maps web paths into filesystem paths and is used to
>     # access content that does not live under the DocumentRoot.
>     # Example:
>     # Alias /webpath /full/filesystem/path
>     #
>     # If you include a trailing / on /webpath then the server will
>     # require it to be present in the URL.  You will also likely
>     # need to provide a <Directory> section to allow access to
>     # the filesystem path.
>
>     #
>     # ScriptAlias: This controls which directories contain server scripts. 
>     # ScriptAliases are essentially the same as Aliases, except that
>     # documents in the target directory are treated as applications and
>     # run by the server when requested rather than as documents sent to the
>     # client.  The same rules about trailing "/" apply to ScriptAlias
>     # directives as to Alias.
>     #
>     ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin/"
>
> </IfModule>
>
> <IfModule cgid_module>
>     #
>     # ScriptSock: On threaded servers, designate the path to the UNIX
>     # socket used to communicate with the CGI daemon of mod_cgid.
>     #
>     #Scriptsock logs/cgisock
> </IfModule>
>
> #
> # "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
> # CGI directory exists, if you have that configured.
> #
> <Directory "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/cgi-bin">
>     AllowOverride None
>     Options None
>     Require all granted
> </Directory>
>
> <IfModule mime_module>
>     #
>     # TypesConfig points to the file containing the list of mappings from
>     # filename extension to MIME-type.
>     #
>     TypesConfig etc/mime.types
>
>     #
>     # AddType allows you to add to or override the MIME configuration
>     # file specified in TypesConfig for specific file types.
>     #
>     #AddType application/x-gzip .tgz
>     #
>     # AddEncoding allows you to have certain browsers uncompress
>     # information on the fly. Note: Not all browsers support this.
>     #
>     #AddEncoding x-compress .Z
>     #AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz
>     #
>     # If the AddEncoding directives above are commented-out, then you
>     # probably should define those extensions to indicate media types:
>     #
>     AddType application/x-compress .Z
>     AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
>
>     #
>     # AddHandler allows you to map certain file extensions to "handlers":
>     # actions unrelated to filetype. These can be either built into the server
>     # or added with the Action directive (see below)
>     #
>     # To use CGI scripts outside of ScriptAliased directories:
>     # (You will also need to add "ExecCGI" to the "Options" directive.)
>     #
>     #AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
>     # XAMPP, since LAMPP 0.9.8:
>     AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl
>
>     # For type maps (negotiated resources):
>     #AddHandler type-map var
>
>     #
>     # Filters allow you to process content before it is sent to the client.
>     #
>     # To parse .shtml files for server-side includes (SSI):
>     # (You will also need to add "Includes" to the "Options" directive.)
>     #
>     # XAMPP
>     AddType text/html .shtml
>     AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
> </IfModule>
>
> #
> # The mod_mime_magic module allows the server to use various hints from the
> # contents of the file itself to determine its type.  The MIMEMagicFile
> # directive tells the module where the hint definitions are located.
> #
> #MIMEMagicFile etc/magic
>
> #
> # Customizable error responses come in three flavors:
> # 1) plain text 2) local redirects 3) external redirects
> #
> # Some examples:
> #ErrorDocument 500 "The server made a boo boo."
> #ErrorDocument 404 /missing.html
> #ErrorDocument 404 "/cgi-bin/missing_handler.pl"
> #ErrorDocument 402 http://www.example.com/subscription_info.html
> #
>
> #
> # MaxRanges: Maximum number of Ranges in a request before
> # returning the entire resource, or one of the special
> # values 'default', 'none' or 'unlimited'.
> # Default setting is to accept 200 Ranges.
> #MaxRanges unlimited
>
> #
> # EnableMMAP and EnableSendfile: On systems that support it, 
> # memory-mapping or the sendfile syscall may be used to deliver
> # files.  This usually improves server performance, but must
> # be turned off when serving from networked-mounted 
> # filesystems or if support for these functions is otherwise
> # broken on your system.
> # Defaults: EnableMMAP On, EnableSendfile Off
> #
> EnableMMAP off
> EnableSendfile off
>
> # Supplemental configuration
> #
> # The configuration files in the etc/extra/ directory can be 
> # included to add extra features or to modify the default configuration of 
> # the server, or you may simply copy their contents here and change as 
> # necessary.
>
> # Server-pool management (MPM specific)
> #Include etc/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
>
> # Multi-language error messages
> Include etc/extra/httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf
>
> # Fancy directory listings
> Include etc/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
>
> # Language settings
> #Include etc/extra/httpd-languages.conf
>
> # User home directories
> #Include etc/extra/httpd-userdir.conf
>
> # Real-time info on requests and configuration
> #Include etc/extra/httpd-info.conf
>
> # Virtual hosts
> #Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
>
> # Local access to the Apache HTTP Server Manual
> #Include etc/extra/httpd-manual.conf
>
> # Distributed authoring and versioning (WebDAV)
> #Include etc/extra/httpd-dav.conf
>
> # Various default settings
> Include etc/extra/httpd-default.conf
>
> # Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
> <IfModule proxy_html_module>
> Include etc/extra/proxy-html.conf
> </IfModule>
>
> # Secure (SSL/TLS) connections
> <IfModule ssl_module>
> # XAMPP
> <IfDefine SSL>
> Include etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
> </IfDefine>
> </IfModule>
> #
> # Note: The following must must be present to support
> #       starting without SSL on platforms with no /dev/random equivalent
> #       but a statically compiled-in mod_ssl.
> #
> <IfModule ssl_module>
> SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
> SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
> </IfModule>
>
> # XAMPP
> Include etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
> Include "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/conf/httpd.conf"
> ```

Comment: Nothing in your configuration file. Problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Have you seen this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036915/my-http-localhost-redirecting-to-www-localhost-com

Answer (score 2):

To disable this "feature" do the following:

- Type `about:config` in the browser bar
- Type `browser.fixup.alternate.enabled` in the search box that appears
- Right click on the browser.fixup.alternate.enabled that appears in the filtered list below and choose "Toggle" to set the value to false

Source: https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/disable-firefox-redirecting-to-localhost-com/

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to not disable this feature I suggest you head to system preferences and network and find your IP address whereupon you can use that in the url bar instead of the `localhost`