# When I open localhost/projectname then it redirects to www.localhost.com/projectname/

Tags: php, redirect, drupal, ubuntu-12.04

When I open any drupal project at URL localhost/projectname then it redirects to www.localhost.com/projectname/

I am using Ubuntu. Please suggest me , How to resolve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: It may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036915/my-http-localhost-redirecting-to-www-localhost-com

Comment: @pradeep1991singh, I am using Mozila.

Comment: See this may help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822683/drupal-localhost-redirecting-to-www-localhost-com?rq=1

Comment: Thank you @pradeep1991singh, According to your recent given URL In my url '.com' is removed but 'www' now still there. Currently, It's showing like www.localhost/projectname/ . Is there any solution to remove of www from the URL.